# Let $U_{r}(a)\subset X$. For $x,y\in U_{r}(a)$ there exist a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to X$ such that its image is entirely in $U_{r}(a)$.

Tags: proof-explanation

Claim:
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $U_{r}(a)\subset X$ with $\epsilon >0$ and $a\in X$. For every tow points $x,y\in U_{r}(a)$ there exist a continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=x$, $ f(1)=y$ and its image lies entirely in $U_{r}(a)$.

Proof:

Define $f:[0,1]\rightarrow U_{r}(a), t\mapsto x+t(y-x)$.
Then $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.

### I don't get the next step:

The entire image of $f$ lies in $U_r(a)$, because from $d(x,y)<1$ and $d(y,a)<1$ it follows:
$$d(f(t),a))=||f(t)-a||=||x+t(y-x)-a||=|| (1-t)(x-a)+t(y-a) ||\\ \leq || (1-t)||x-a||+t||y-a||<(1-t)+t=1 \quad\quad q.e.d.$$

I understand the equivalence transformations, but it was only shown that $d(f(t),a)<1$ holds.But the proof is not elaborated further.
Actually one has to show that for every $t\in[0,1]$,  $d(f(t),a)<r$ holds, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in the setup, "because from $d(x,y)<1$ and $d(y,a)<1$", which is repeated in the last inequality, $||x-a||$ and $||y-a||$ are less than $r$, not less than $1$. Thus the final inequality is
$$
\dots < (1-t)r + tr = r
$$

Comment: "... because from $d(x,a)<r$ and $d(y,a)<r$ it follows..." would be correct?

Comment: yep, that would be one way to correctly rewrite this